# Excel VBA - Delete rows on multiple values from a single column filter

Tags: excel, filter, delete-row, vba

I have written code which deletes rows based on a SINGLE input value from a single column filter, I want to edit this to handle multiple input values from the same column filter.

The database's header is on A4:Z.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim myValue As Variant

   'set sheet reference
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    'turn off autofilter
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False

    'get last row
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'set range to filter
    Set rng = ws.Range("A4:Z" & lastRow)

    'get user input
    myValue = InputBox("Periods to delete?")

    'set filter
    rng.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=myValue

    'delete visible rows
    rng.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete

    'show remaining rows by removing autofilter
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```

The input box takes a single period (month number) at present. I want it to take multiple values like so '2,3,4'. This will delete 2 (feb), 3 (march), 4 (april).

Really not sure what to do next, I'm still a newb to vba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the autofilter line with this. It assumes the values are entered in the input box separated by commas. It converts them into an array.

```
rng.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=Array(Split(myValue, ",")), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: really sorry but is there a way the code can catch a value like this: "16m1-16m5"? doesnt seem to do anything.

Comment: If you mean the separator is a hyphen rather than a comma, just change the second Split parameter to a hyphen.

Comment: no sorry, the value is literally "16m1-16m5". The example I'm trying is: "16m1, 16m4, 16m1-16m5"

Comment: That should work - is the value definitely there? Try changing the parameter to ", " if you have a space after the comma.

Comment: Not sure what I was doing wrong but you're right it does work! sorry about that :)